# nginx can't load images,css,js

Tags: nginx

When I point to a URL in nginx where it has images extension such as:

http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png (as example)

it gives me the 404 error as it can't find the file, but the file is actually there. What is potentially wrong?

UPDATE:

Here's the error log that I was able to pull out:

```
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *225 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/js/mooRainbow/mooRainbow.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/js/mooRainbow/mooRainbow.css HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *226 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/print.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/print.css HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *228 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *223 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/b_help.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/b_help.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *227 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/s_warn.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/s_warn.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:53:29 [error] 18679#0: *227 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *237 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/print.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/print.css HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *235 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/js/mooRainbow/mooRainbow.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/js/mooRainbow/mooRainbow.css HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *238 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *239 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/b_help.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/b_help.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *233 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/s_warn.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/s_warn.png HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42", referrer: "http://50.56.81.42/phpMyAdmin/main.php"
2011/02/27 05:54:39 [error] 18679#0: *233 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 70.176.18.156, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "50.56.81.42"
```

Here's my nginx.conf file, in case I am missing something:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html)$ {
                 expires max;
        }


        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

What does this mean? It can't pull out the .css, etc....

Comment: Which OS, is selinux enabled ( check with getsebool ), what does ls -l /usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png show?

Comment: it gives ls: /usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png: No such file or directory, why is that? the file is there

Comment: getsebool:  SELinux is disabled, how to enable?

Comment: Umm, equinox, PHP says /usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/themes/original/img/logo_right.png isn't there, `ls` says it isn't there; may I ask what makes you think it **is** there?

Comment: sorry, I meant it exists in /usr/share/nginx/html/......

Comment: So why are you telling Nginx it exists in /usr/local/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/?

Comment: where did I say that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix all your

```
 root html;
```

lines to actually have a path (like your .php block does), it appears that nginix is picking the wrong "html" directory since you didn't say which "html" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the error log. It may be a permission problem or a misconfiguration on the server.